# How can I convert photo (or video) from camera to NSData?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, alassetslibrary

In my app I take photo and then save url to it using ALAssetsLibrary. This code looks like this:

```
   ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: image.imageOrientation.rawValue)!,
                completionBlock:{ (path:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    if(error == nil){
                           path.save()
                           //.......
                    }
            })
```

I need to transform the photo that I took to NSData object. So how can I substitute this code according to IOS 9.0 guidelines (I know that ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated in IOS 9)? And how can I transform my photo to NSData object?

Comment: Just use this function in your block. `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated, you should use the Photos library. See below code example.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({

    let assetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)

    }, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in

    if success {
        //image saved to photos library.
    }
})
```

If you need to transform the image to NSData, you could simply use (as pointed out by @if-else-switch )

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Ryuk yes it will

Comment: @mohonish do you know how we can edit/update existing image ? we don't want to create new image.

Answer (score 0):

For Photo/Video Do this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]]];
```